# how to use "?" as a string in URl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, routes

i m having issue with  "?" sign in Url

Example: my Url is like

> /discussion/how%20to%20pass%20css%20exam?-1

But  this "?" removes everything after it.
if my url will be this

> /discussion/how%20to%20pass?%20css%20exam-1

then it removes  20css%20exam-1  from url

here is my Route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "discussionDetail",
        url: "discussion/{Url}-{ID}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Discussion", action = "Detail",Url = "" }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `%3f` (the ASCII code of `?` is 63 or 0x3F).